# Laravel old() input occasionally returns an array

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

My bug tracker shows some exceptions for the following Blade lines:

```html
<input
    type="email"
    id="email"
    name="email"
    value="{{ old('email') }}"
>
```

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

This is caused by the `old()` helper which somehow retrieves an array for `'email'` instead of a string.

Now normally, when submitting a form with this input, the `old('email')` value should just contain a string when the controller redirects back for validation purposes. However, I've noticed that some hack scripts are being ran on my applications where they try to break stuff by sending specific POST payloads and trying out urls.

One of these payloads must be of the form of `&email[]=abc&email[]=def` or some other syntax that sends the email input as an array. The default login validator `'email' => 'required|string'` does not seem to filter it, end I end up with an error in the view.

I'm looking for an easy way to get rid of this exception with as little code as possible, since this happens in many views. Something like this would suffice but it is a little convoluted since it retrieves the `'email'` key twice from the session:

```php
{{ is_string(old('email')) ? old('email') : null }}
```

So any suggestions are welcome to shorten this syntax, preferably one that does not retrieve session variables twice.

**EDIT**: the `required|string` validation *does* seem to only allow strings, so you cant send an array. However, the actual error will happen when this ValidationException is sent to the view, which in turn calls `old('email')` which will return whatever was passed (in this case an array even though it is invalid).

Comment: you could also make your own function that does that and call your function, then it is just a function call, no ternary

Comment: yes you're right, i made an elegant solution, i'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to make a new function that is a slightly modified version of `old()`:

```php
// app/helpers.php


if (!function_exists('old_string')) {
    /**
     * Wrapper for `old()` helper that doesn't break when arrays manage to get in.
     * @param string $key
     * @param mixed $default
     * @return string|null
     */
    function old_string($key, $default = null)
    {
        $val = old($key, $default);
        return is_string($val) ? $val : null;
    }
}
```

This way I can use `old_string('email')` in my views where I specifically expect strings, without messing with the original function.

Answer (score 0):

if old function return empty array that means you passed null as attr

Comment: no it means i passed an array. `old()` will return whatever you sent